# FullCalendar error when using PrimeNG Schedule

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I am on Angular 2.4 and am trying to use PrimeNG's schedule, but I'm getting errors. If you go to the following link, you will see an example of the schedule, plus documentation if you scroll down the page:

http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule

I followed that documentation (with the only difference being that I changed "MyModel" to "CalendarComponent"), but got the following error:

> Error in calendar.component.html:0:0 caused by:
>   this.schedule.fullCalendar is not a function

Is this because I need to install and import FullCalendar? I figured that might be the case, but when I attempted to import it, I got the following 404:

> https://localhost:44301/node_modules/fullcalendar/fullcalendar 404 ()

Here is my code after attempting to import FullCalendar...

**app.module.ts:**

```
...
import { FullCalendar }      from 'fullcalendar/fullcalendar';
import { ScheduleModule }    from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CalendarComponent } from './calendar.component';
...
imports: [
    ...
    FullCalendar,
    ScheduleModule
],
declarations: [
    ...
    CalendarComponent
],
...
```

**calendar.component.ts:**

```
...
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
    events: any[];
    headerConfig: any;

    public constructor(
        ...
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.events = [
            {
                "title": "All Day Event",
                "start": "2016-01-01"
            },
            {
                "title": "Long Event",
                "start": "2016-01-07",
                "end": "2016-01-10"
            },
            {
                "title": "Repeating Event",
                "start": "2016-01-09T16:00:00"
            },
            {
                "title": "Repeating Event",
                "start": "2016-01-16T16:00:00"
            },
            {
                "title": "Conference",
                "start": "2016-01-11",
                "end": "2016-01-13"
            }
        ];
        this.headerConfig = {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        };        
    }


    handleEventClick(e:any) {
        //e.event = Selected event
        //e.jsEvent = Browser click event
        //e.view = Current view object
        console.log('Selected event: ' + e.event);
        console.log('Browser click event: ' + e.jsEvent);
        console.log('Current view object: ' + e.view);
    }       
}
```

**calendar.component.html:**

```
<p-schedule [events]="events" [header]="headerConfig" (onEventClick)="handleEventClick($event)"></p-schedule>
```

**systemjs.config.js:**

```
map: {
    ...
    'fullcalendar': 'npm:fullcalendar',
    'primeng':      'npm:primeng'
},
```

**package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "fullcalendar": "^3.1.0",
    "primeng": "^1.1.4",
  },
```

Comment: PrimeFaces != PrimeNG. Corrected tagging

Comment: PrimeNG still using a Angular2 version below the one you are using. I'm also using PrimeNG on a huge project, and I had bad experience setting my version from any above the version described at the package.json example from the prime website. Our issues occur basically when building for production, with lots of missing stuff. Could be the same as yours.

Comment: How do you build for production? I use AOT compiler.

Comment: @Fals Also, do you ever have issues locally? Or just when building for prod?

Comment: @Brett only when built for production

Answer (score 3):

In order to make the p-scheduler work you must include jquery and moment and its types definition on your project:

Configuration that works for me. Using Angular CLI

**package.son**
`

```
> "dependencies": {
>     "fullcalendar": "^3.2.0",
>     "jquery": "^3.1.1",
>     "moment": "^2.17.1",
>     "primeng": "2.0.1",  },
> 
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.32.3",
>     "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
>     "@types/fullcalendar": "^2.7.37",
>     "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
>     "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40",
>     "@types/moment": "^2.13.0", }
```

`

**scheduler.module.ts**

```
`
import 'jquery';
import 'moment';
import 'fullcalendar';

import { ScheduleModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
```

**angular-cli,json**

```
      "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",     
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"
  ],
```

The component It is defined similar as your.

Answer (score 1):

**I am using primeng api with fullcalendar api**

**app.module.ts**

```
    import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
    (window as any).jQuery = (window as any).$ = jQuery;
    import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';
    import 'fullcalendar';
    import 'fullcalendar-scheduler';

    @NgModule({
    declarations:[ TriggerResizeDirective,....],
    imports: [ ScheduleModule,MomentModule...],..
```

**Calendar.component.ts**

```
    import * as moment from 'moment';
    import { Schedule } from 'primeng/primeng';
    import * as $ from 'jquery';
    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    public  heading: any;
    public  events: any[];

    ngOnInit() {
    this.events = [
    {
      "title": "All Day Event",
      "start": "2018-03-01"
    },
    {
      "title": "Long Event",
      "start": "2016-01-07",
      "end": "2018-02-10"
    }];
```

**dashCalendar.component.html**

```
      <p-schedule id="calendar" ></p-schedule>
```

**Below link will help many**

[enter link description here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule)

[enter link description here](https://fullcalendar.io/)

Comment: Putting the imports exactly like this worked for us...wish we had the time to figure out exactly why. Thanks! Note: we did not use/need the MomentModule import or fullcalendar-scheduler import.

Answer (score 0):

Try put this on **`main.ts`**:

```
import fullcalendar from 'fullcalendar';
window['fullcalendar'] = fullcalendar;
```